# Append excel file gives error and corrupts file

Tags: python, python-3.x, excel, pandas

I am trying to write extracted values from html files and append them to an existing excel worksheet.The value extraction part works, and it prints it when I prompt it to.

This is the code

```
import pandas as pd
import xlwt
from xlwt import Workbook
from openpyxl import load_workbook
fn = r'C:\Users\Ahmed_Abdelmuniem\PycharmProjects\Pandas Parser\Survey.xlsx'



file = r'C:\Users\Ahmed_Abdelmuniem\Desktop\XXX.html'
table = pd.read_html(file)


i=3

filtered_table = [df for df in table if len(df) > 2]

for df in filtered_table:
    comp = df.iat[1,0]

    if comp == 'YYY' :
        name = df.iat[0,0]
        print (name)
        writer = pd.ExcelWriter(fn, engine='openpyxl')
        book = load_workbook(fn)
        writer.book = book
        writer.sheets = dict((ws.title, ws) for ws in book.worksheets)
        name.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1', header=None, index=False,
                     startcol=4, startrow=i)
        writer.save()
        i=i+1
```

However I am receiving the follow traceback and the file gets corrupted.

```
C:\Users\Ahmed_Abdelmuniem\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python.exe "C:/Users/Ahmed_Abdelmuniem/PycharmProjects/Pandas Parser/main.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Ahmed_Abdelmuniem\PycharmProjects\Pandas Parser\main.py", line 29, in <module>
    book = load_workbook(fn)
  File "C:\Users\Ahmed_Abdelmuniem\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\reader\excel.py", line 315, in load_workbook
    reader = ExcelReader(filename, read_only, keep_vba,
  File "C:\Users\Ahmed_Abdelmuniem\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\reader\excel.py", line 124, in __init__
    self.archive = _validate_archive(fn)
  File "C:\Users\Ahmed_Abdelmuniem\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\reader\excel.py", line 96, in _validate_archive
    archive = ZipFile(filename, 'r')
  File "C:\Users\Ahmed_Abdelmuniem\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\zipfile.py", line 1257, in __init__
INW
    self._RealGetContents()
  File "C:\Users\Ahmed_Abdelmuniem\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\zipfile.py", line 1324, in _RealGetContents
    raise BadZipFile("File is not a zip file")
zipfile.BadZipFile: File is not a zip file

Process finished with exit code 1
```