# Nested for loop being ignored

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a nested for loop, however it is being ignored, I am not sure why.

```
import pandas as pd
import shutil
import os
import glob

source_dir = r'C:\Users\Ahmed_Abdelmuniem\Desktop\GLift'
target_dir = r'C:\Users\Ahmed_Abdelmuniem\Desktop\TAfternoon'

file_names = glob.glob(os.path.join(source_dir, '*.html'))

for file_name in file_names:

    table = pd.read_html(file_name)
    print ('tables found:', len(table))
    for table in file_name:
        filtered_table = [df for df in table if len(df) > 2]
        for df in filtered_table:
            comp = df.iat[1, 0]
            if comp == 'SLS':
                name = df.iat[0,0]
                print (name)
```

The output is as follows:

```
:\Users\Ahmed_Abdelmuniem\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python.exe "C:/Users/Ahmed_Abdelmuniem/PycharmProjects/File mover V2.0/main.py"
tables found: 73
tables found: 73
tables found: 71
tables found: 72
tables found: 123
tables found: 124
tables found: 123
tables found: 124
tables found: 123
tables found: 72
tables found: 72
tables found: 123
tables found: 121
tables found: 122
tables found: 119
tables found: 125
tables found: 124
tables found: 121
tables found: 121
tables found: 120
tables found: 122
tables found: 121

Process finished with exit code 0
```

As you can see, it is only executing the first for loop, and not the second one as it is not printing the name variable.

Edit: For clarification I have shown that the code works when not nested.

This is the code that works on its own to extract the data, however it doesn't work when nested.

```
import pandas as pd
import xlwt
from xlwt import Workbook
from openpyxl import load_workbook
fn = r'C:\Users\Ahmed_Abdelmuniem\PycharmProjects\Pandas Parser\Survey.xlsx'



file = r'C:\Users\Ahmed_Abdelmuniem\Desktop\XXX.html'
table = pd.read_html(file)


i=3

filtered_table = [df for df in table if len(df) > 2]

for df in filtered_table:
    comp = df.iat[1,0]

    if comp == 'SLS' :
        name = df.iat[0,0]
        print (name)
```

This is the output from another code to show that there is indeed data in there.

```
C:\Users\Ahmed_Abdelmuniem\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python.exe "C:/Users/Ahmed_Abdelmuniem/PycharmProjects/Pandas Parser/main.py"
INW
SPL

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Several conditions need to be met before your print statement in the inner loop. For example, `filtered_table` must have at least one item and `comp == 'SLS'`.  How do you know the inner loop is not running rather than those conditions not being met?

Comment: Check whether filtered_table list has any data or is it empty. 
After that check if any data fulfills your second if condition (comp == 'SLS')

Comment: I have checked that it is fulfilled in another code, I am now just combining individual codes into a bigger one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your following working code

```py
file = r'C:\Users\Ahmed_Abdelmuniem\Desktop\XXX.html'
table = pd.read_html(file)

filtered_table = [df for df in table if len(df) > 2]

for df in filtered_table:
    comp = df.iat[1,0]

    if comp == 'SLS' :
        name = df.iat[0,0]
        print (name)
```

You are doing,

1. Read table with `pd.read_html(file)`
2. Filter table with `[df for df in table if len(df) > 2]`

However, in your nested loop, you are doing

1. Read table with `pd.read_html(file_name)`
2. Unknown for-in `for table in file_name`.
3. Filter table with `[df for df in table if len(df) > 2]`

```py
for file_name in file_names:
    table = pd.read_html(file_name)
    print ('tables found:', len(table))
    for table in file_name:
        filtered_table = [df for df in table if len(df) > 2] 
        #                               ^
        #                               |
        #                              table here is file_name
        for df in filtered_table:
            comp = df.iat[1, 0]
            if comp == 'SLS':
                name = df.iat[0,0]
                print (name)
```

You might need to remove the `for table in file_name` line

```py
for file_name in file_names:

    table = pd.read_html(file_name)
    print ('tables found:', len(table))

    filtered_table = [df for df in table if len(df) > 2]
    for df in filtered_table:
        comp = df.iat[1, 0]
        if comp == 'SLS':
            name = df.iat[0,0]
            print (name)
```

Comment: Alright wow, it worked, but how come the 'for table in file_name' is redundant?

Comment: @Ahmed If it is not redundant, what do you want to do?

Comment: what I mean is, I don't understand the logic of how it is redundant?

Comment: @Ahmed By using `for table in file_name` you are looping each character in `file_name` string.

Comment: thank you so very much for the solution and clarification. You seem to be a very valuable member of this community, you provide solutions and lessons. Stay blessed.

Comment: I am not sure if this is allowed, if it isn't please ignore it, but could you maybe provide some help with this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67057325/append-excel-file-gives-error-and-corrupts-file

Comment: @Ahmed Sorry, I have never used openpyxl before. I can't give you any advice.

Comment: Thanks a bunch man, you've helped plenty, cheers.